# Excel: Lookup date using a number and display data that corresponds with that number

Tags: excel

I am trying to enter a number in one sheet and i want to look into another sheet for information that corresponds with that number.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

So i want to enter a number in No and i want it to look on the other sheet under No and look for the number and then copy the information that corresponds with number 2 and display it in the right cell like naam, inhoud (t), etc..

Example:

Sheet 1: No 2
Sheet 2: Looks for No 2 finds it select information
Sheet 1: Naam is copyed inhoud (t) is copied Kg is copied LCG is copied.

I hope someone understand what i mean because i cant really explain it so good.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So why doesn't vlookup work?

Comment: I can't select the multiple tables. It wont accept the formula

Comment: Use IFERROR to pass control to a second vlookup if the first doesn't match.

Comment: Used the IFERROR now it works like i want it to. Thanks